# how to run java console with parameters

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I'm setting teamcity agent using my account and there are no admin rights, so I got error

> Current Java runtime version is 1.7 
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/08/21 16:03:57 | Starting new process with command line ('|' arguments separator): C:\QA\volAgent\jre\bin\java|-classpath|C:\QA\volAgent\update\launcher\lib\launcher.jar|jetbrains.buildServer.agent.upgrade.Upgrade|NT_SERVICE|C:\QA\volAgent|-ea|-Xmx512m|-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError|-Xrs|-Dlog4j.configuration=file:../conf/teamcity-agent-log4j.xml|-Dteamcity_logs=../logs/|jetbrains.buildServer.agent.AgentMain|-file|../conf/buildAgent.properties| in directory: C:\QA\volAgent 
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/08/21 16:03:57 | Launcher is waiting to be killed by upgrade process 
>   FATAL  | wrapper  | 2015/08/21 16:04:01 | OpenSCManager failed - Access is denied. (0x5)
>   FATAL  | wrapper  | 2015/08/21 16:04:01 | OpenSCManager failed - Access is denied. (0x5)

Error occurs because my local user does not have required permission, but I have admin console opened, and all I need is to run script above manually in admin console. I tried many cases but it doesn't work, can anybody help?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token ?

Comment: thanks, but I know how to run console as admin, at my work admin console can be opened only by admin, so I have such console, point is how to run script above in this console

Comment: the same way you run it on a regular console. (You should be able to drag and drop the icon from somewhere to the shell and press return)

Comment: ))ok...and how to run it on regular console?